# Convert an ArrayFormula to its equivalent normal Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, count, distinct

so I have the following ArrayFormula that counts distinct values in a list that can be filtered.:

```
{=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(C8,ROW(C8:C11508)-ROW(C8),0))=1) *(C8:C11508<>""), MATCH(C8:C11508,C8:C11508,0)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(C8:C11508)))))}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same results using a non ArrayFormula?

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The ideal result is count distinct values in a list that can be filtered using a single non ArrayFormula. Helper columns are fine if one formula solution is undoable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want array formulas you will have to start thinking about using helper columns, here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)<2)*1
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=1*SUBTOTAL(3,$C2)
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=IF($D2,$A2,"-")
```

Formula in `F2`:

```
=($E2<>"-")*(COUNTIF($E$2:$E2,$E2)<2)
```

Formula in `H1`:

```
=SUM(F2:F9)
```

Filtering on column B applied:

[image]

You'll find some more information [here](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/10/04/count-unique-items-in-excel-filtered-list/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and thorough response. However, for some reason the result is sometimes when filtering off by a narrow margin. Any ideas on why? I can provide a demo Excel file if you want.

Comment: You could use something straigtforward like [this](https://uploadfiles.io/). Maybe rework your question and add the aditional information. What is expected, where is the error etc. Also make sure that it's sample data as you should not share business information (plus it is easy to work with). I won't have time till later today to look at it though.

Comment: Thanks, I reworked the question. Talk to you later.

Comment: It worked! It was a mishap from my part. Thank you so much for your elegant solution.

Comment: @HoussamHaddad, I just looked at it, column Helper4 had a wrong cell reference. Glad it has been helpfull.